# rmarkdown: render to .pdf using existing .md files created for .html

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Is that possible at all? At the moment I have to render my .Rmd files twice, once for an html and once for a pdf report. Each of them take about 50 mins. So if I can use the html .md files created after rendering, that would save me 50 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.md` document is already created, you can simply use:

```
library("rmarkdown")
render("mydoc.md", output_format = "pdf_document")
```

If you always need to generate both html and pdf, then render both at the same time using J_F's solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the markdown output of knitr with `keep_md: yes`

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
---
```

Then, using pandoc, you can produce your pdf from this file; in a terminal (not a R console):

```
pandoc mydoc.md -o mydoc.pdf
```

You'll have to install pandoc if you haven't already, to use it without knitr.

You might loose a few things, though, because knitr adapts its md intermediary file to the final output.

Comment: I think that might actually be output: 
  html_document: 
    keep_md: yes

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to render multiple outputs, but not with the "knit" Button in RStudio. Write your desired output in the YAML header and then use output_format = "all" as argument in

```
rmarkdown::render(<your-rmd-file.rmd>, output_format ="all")
```

So the YAML header looks like:

```
title: "multiple outputs"
output:
     pdf_document: default
     html_document: default
```

Or any option you want to set for the different output formats.

Comment: Hmm, looks like this approach does rendering one by one, every time creating .md files for a new format. So, it does not really save time by not creating new .md files.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can tell the compiler to keep the intermediate .md file.   Then, you can easily compile that into other formats.

Go to:
1.  RStudio > Open your .Rmd file
2.  Click on the Gear (settings) drop down and choose `Output Options`
3.  Choose `Advanced`
4.  Check `Keep markdown source file`
5. Click OK
6. `Knit to HTML`
7. Open .md file in editor
8. In Gear (settings) drop down, select PDF as Output Format, AND select `(No Preview)`
9. In the Preview dropdown, select `Preview PDF` and a .pdf file should be created

As an alternative to steps 2-5, edit your file so that the header includes:

```
---
title: "blah blah"
output: 
  html_document: 
    keep_md: yes
---
```